# Apache poi word document null pointer exception

Tags: java, exception, ms-word, apache-poi

I have written a string in word document. But when I open the document to get the string and store it in another document it gives me exception.

This is my code.

```
 XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
   XWPFParagraph paragraphOne = document.createParagraph();
    XWPFRun paragraphOneRunOne = paragraphOne.createRun();
    paragraphOneRunOne.setBold(true);
    paragraphOneRunOne.setItalic(true);
    paragraphOneRunOne.setText("Hello world! This is paragraph one!");
    paragraphOneRunOne.addBreak();


    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream("MyDov.docx");
        document.write(outStream);
        outStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("MyDov.docx"));
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(is); //Document with words
        XWPFWordExtractor ex = new XWPFWordExtractor(doc);  //To get the words
        String words = ex.getText();

         XWPFDocument newDoc = new XWPFDocument(); //Doc to write new doc to
     XWPFParagraph para = newDoc.createParagraph(); //Paragraph
     XWPFRun run = para.createRun();     
          run.setText(words);
              }
        newDoc.write(new FileOutputStream(new File("mydoc.docx")));}
    catch (IOException e)
    {System.out.println(e);}
```

It gives me this exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.XWPFWordExtractor.extractHeaders(XWPFWordExtractor.java:162)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.XWPFWordExtractor.getText(XWPFWordExtractor.java:87)
    at atestpack.CreateDocumentFromScratch.main(CreateDocumentFromScratch.java:56)

How can I solve this exception?
```

Comment: You are writing your document and then immediately reading it. Did you try to check that document is OK? Did you try to open it with MS word compatible application? Did you try to read *other*, definitely valid word document?

Comment: Yes this document is OK There is a sentence written Hello world! This is paragraph one! and I have opened it with wordpad. I have read other document which are created my me through code.

Comment: So, attach sources of POI and try to go through the stack with debugger. The stack trace is not too deep and you will easily see why NPE is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unsure if it is to do with the way you are writing to the document but when you retrieve the text it seems to expect you to do it paragraph by paragraph. In the below I have retrieved each paragraph from the document, cycled through them retrieving text and then writing it out as you wanted. I have commented what I have changed below:

```
public class SO3 {
public static void main(String[] args){

XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
XWPFParagraph paragraphOne = document.createParagraph();
XWPFRun paragraphOneRunOne = paragraphOne.createRun();
paragraphOneRunOne.setBold(true);
paragraphOneRunOne.setItalic(true);
paragraphOneRunOne.setText("Hello world! This is paragraph one!");
paragraphOneRunOne.addBreak();

try {
    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("D:\\Users\\user2777005\\Desktop\\MyDov.docx");
    document.write(outStream);
    outStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try{
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\Users\\user2777005\\Desktop\\MyDov.docx"));

XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(is);
List<XWPFParagraph> paras = doc.getParagraphs(); //This list will hold the paragraphs
XWPFWordExtractor ex = new XWPFWordExtractor(doc);  //To get the words
String words = ""; //This will hold all the text
    for(XWPFParagraph p : paras){  //For each paragraph we retrieved from the document
      words += p.getText();    //Add the text we retrieve to the words string  
    }

    System.out.println(words); //Check out string
    XWPFDocument newDoc = new XWPFDocument(); 
    XWPFParagraph para = newDoc.createParagraph();
    XWPFRun run = para.createRun();     
   //You have to reformat the run with bold/italic e.t.c if you want
    run.setText(words);
    newDoc.write(new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\Users\\user2777005\\Desktop\\mydoc.docx")));}
   catch (IOException e)
{System.out.println(e);}
}}
```

Good Luck!